# How to expose an Environment Variable to the front end in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, environment-variables

## The Problem

I am trying to pass an environment variable to the front end to display a map from MapBox.

## My Attempts

1. I have place the API Key into the root of my directory:

```
//.env.local
MAPBOX_KEY="abc123"
```

2. In the front-end, client side, I am trying to load that ENV to render a map:

```js
// components/MapBox.js
export default function MapBox(){
  const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.MAPBOX_KEY

  return (
    <MapGL mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} />
  )
}
```

The above code does not seem to recgonize the API KEY.

3. When I console.log(process.env.MAPBOX_KEY) in this component, I can see the API Key in the terminal while i'm running `yarn dev`

Is there a way to load this env to the front end?

*Note: I am using the `react-map-gl` package built on top of MapBox*

Answer (score 8):

You need to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

Only variables with that prefix will be exposed in the frontend

For example `NEXT_PUBLIC_HEY` will be visible for the frontend but both for the backend.

```
MAPBOX_KEY="abc123"
NEXT_PUBLIC_HEY="FRONT"
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Does this mean that the variable is still unexposed to the browser meaning that people can't steal it?

Comment: Everything prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` will be exposed. There is no `process.env` for the frontend. What the framework does is that it looks for all env variables during the  build(because the build is os level operation, it knows what env variables are) prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` creates custom `process.env` in frontend and injects values one by one. So, the values are in your source code, whoever has access to it can see all, it is served from the browser which means everyone can access it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to prefix your ENV with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in `.env.local`

```
//.env.local
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_KEY="abc123"
```

In your component, reference it like this:

```
// MapBox.js
export default function MapBox(){
  const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_KEY

  return (
    <MapGL mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Here's the [doc link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) for reference

Answer (score 2):

```
// Normal Env
   VERY_SECRET
// PUBLIC ENV
   NEXT_PUBLIC_NOT_SO_SECRET
```

Add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` PREFIX